# Why does AtomicPtr disallow dynamically sized types?

Tags: rust

I wanted to create an `AtomicPtr` to a slice but I was surprised to find out that I couldn't.

```
struct MyObject {
    ptr: AtomicPtr<[u32]>
}
```

yields the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u32]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     ptr: AtomicPtr<[u32]>
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u32]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required by `std::sync::atomic::AtomicPtr`
```

See it on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c8c6beb06ac1775f57265418aa2ec9b)

I personally can't see why this would be the case but I might be missing something. Is there a reason for this restriction? And is there a workaround for achieving the same functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is intentional that `AtomicPtr<T>` works only with `T: Sized` because in rust 
slices and trait objects are fat pointers (the size double respect to normal pointer).

Actually it is not possible to have `T: ?Sized` because this prevents the guarantee of atomic operation
for some platforms, for example ARM.

See [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24223) for more details.